# Swift 3 replacingOccurrences regex

Tags: regex, swift

I'm having trouble with my replacingOccurrences function. I have a string like so:

```
let x = "&john &johnny &johnney"
```

What I need to do is remove only "&john"

So I have this code:

```
y = "&john"
x = x.replacingOccurrences(of: y, with: " ", options: NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

The problem I get is that this removes All instances of john... And I'm left with:

```
"ny ney"
```

Also I thought about setting the range, however, that wont really solve my problem because the names could be in a different order.

Comment: What should happen with `"&john, &john! '&john'"` ?

Answer (score 9):

First of all your code does not compile because `x` must be `var`.

To remove only `&John` with regular expression you need to check if the end of the query is a word boundary:

```
var x = "&john &johnny &johnney"

let pattern = "&john\\b"
x = x.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
```

Or more convenient in Swift 5.7+

```
let pattern = /&john\b/
x.replace(pattern, with: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces to the string so that it becomes `" &john "`. Now it does not remove unnecessary characters.

However, if `&john` is the first or last in the list of names, this will not work. To solve this, you just need to check if the string has a suffix or prefix of `&john` by calling `hasSuffix` and `hasPrefix`.

Actually, I just thought of a better solution:

```
x = x.components(separatedBy: " ").
    filter { $0 != "&john" }.joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to include a space at the end of the string you want to remove:

`y = "&john "`